# Obtain values from multiple distributions with a single generator roll

Tags: c++, random, c++17, entropy

I am trying to implement the [Alias method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_method), also described [here](http://www.keithschwarz.com/darts-dice-coins/). This is an algorithm which allows to sample from a weighted N-sided dice in O(1).

The algorithm calls for the generation of two values:

- An uniformly distributed integer `i` in [0, N]
- An uniformly distributed real `y` in [0, 1)

The paper specifies that these two numbers can be obtained by a single real number `x` between `[0, N)`. From `x` one can then derive two values as:

- `i = floor(x)`
- `y = x - i`

Now, the other implementations that I have seen call for the random number generator two times, one to generate `i` and one to generate `y`. Given that I am using a fairly expensive generator (`std::mt19937`) and that I need to sample many times, I was wondering if there was a better approach in terms of performance, while preserving the quality of the result.

I'm not sure whether using an `uniform_real_distribution` to generate `x` makes sense as if `N` is large then `y`'s distribution is going to get sparser as `double`s are not uniformly distributed. Is there maybe a way to call the engine, get the random bits out, and then generate `i` and `y` from them directly?

Comment: I doubt that MT is the bottleneck in your program(unless you keep creating instances of it, and that is just a programmer error). 

Did you profile your code?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl What do you mean? It is a good random generator, and calling it is for example more expensive than calls to `std::default_random_engine` which provides a lower quality stream of numbers. I don't have a particular bottleneck, but I have already tried all that I could. Since I am trying this sampling method might as well write it well. I am going to sample tens of thousands of times overall so any slight improvement helps.

Comment: Most of things in engineering is a tradeoff between time invested and quality. If you are gonna waste time improving something that will not even show in your profile data: have fun.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Not sure if you are here to even contribute anything. I am trying because I don't know how much of an impact it is going to have. In order to decide what to try, I need to be able to make an informed decision. My guess is that this sampling method will improve my performance. I do not have an informed guess on whether doing one or two samples is going to matter much. Still, since I have to implement the method anyway, might as well ask rather than try both (and in the meantime maybe learn something). I'll have fun, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, with their method the distribution of `y` will become less and less uniform with increasing `N`.

In fact, for `N` above 2^52 `y` will be exactly 0, as all numbers above that value are integers for double precision. 2^52 is 4,503,599,627,370,496 (4.5 quadrillion).

It will not matter at all for reasonable values of `N` though. You should be fine if your `N` is less than 2^26 (67 million), intuitively.  Your die does not have an astronomical number of sides, does it?

Comment: I don't have so many sides, thankfully. At the same time, my main concern is the comparison between `y` and the probabilities in the original vector (as they get transformed in the weighted "coins" to compare against). How many digits of precision would I get approximately? It has been a while since I dealt with the floating point standard, and I do not remember exactly how it works.

Comment: Hard to tell, it'll depend on `N` I believe.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, and would tell you how I solved it in my case. It might be applicable to you or not, but here is the story

1. I didn't use any kind of 32bit RNG. Basically, no 32 bit platform and software to care about. So I used [std::mt19937_64](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/mt19937_64/) as baseline generator. One 64bit unsigned int per call. Later I tried to use one of the PCG 64bit RNG, overall faster good outcome.
2. Top `N` bits to be used directly for selection from table (dice in your case). You could suffer from modulo bias, so I managed to extend table to be exact power of 2 (2<sup>10</sup> in my case, 10 bits for index sampling)
3. Remainder 54 bits were used to get uniform double random number following S. Vigna suggestion.
4. If you need more than 11 bits for index, you could either live with reduced randomness in mantissa, or replace `double y` with carefully crafted integer comparison.

Along the lines, some pseudocode (not tested!)

```
uint64_t mask = (1ULL << 53ULL) - 1ULL;

auto seed{ 98765432101ULL };
auto rng = std::mt19937_64{seed};

for (int k = 0; k != 1000; ++k) {
    auto rv = rng();
    auto idx = rv >> uint64_t(64 - 10); // needed only 10 bits for index
    double y = (rv & mask) * (1. / (1ULL << 53ULL)); // 53 bits used for mantissa
    std::cout << idx << "," << y << '\n';
}
```

Reference to S.Vigna integer2double conversion for RNG: http://xoshiro.di.unimi.it/, at the very end of the page